# The code shows an undefined error in python 2.7

Tags: python

my code is :

```
import os
def rename_files():
#1 list all files in one variable
 file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kai Uchiha\Desktop\PYTHON\prank")
print(file_list)
#2 rename those files

rename_files()
```

and it shows an error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Kai
>   Uchiha/Desktop/Projects/experiments/experiment2.py", line 5, in
>   
>       print(file_list) NameError: name 'file_list' is not defined

Comment: `print(file_list)` might not be indented into `rename_files`.

Comment: You assign to `file_list` inside `rename_files` function, so that `file_list` is a local variable in this function; then you try to print it **outside** the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent the `print(file_list)` line so that it is actually a part of the `rename_files` function:

```
def rename_files():
  #1 list all files in one variable
  file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kai Uchiha\Desktop\PYTHON\prank")
  print(file_list)  # NOTE: additional indent!
```

As is, that line is *outside* of the function, and the `file_list` variable does not exist there, hence the error you are seeing.

Comment: Just to add in, [PEP 8 recommends](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) that code indentation levels are 4 spaces apart.

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation error

```
import os
def rename_files():
#1 list all files in one variable
 file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Kai Uchiha\Desktop\PYTHON\prank")
 print(file_list) # Added tab here (it seems that it's only one space for you, but I think it still has to be four spaces...
#2 rename those files

rename_files()
```